# How do I make a form selection go to another page?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, hyperlink

I'm creating a survey for a class project and one of the survey questions requires a dropdown list where the user will select a letter. The idea is when the user selects a letter, the code will link them to another website. So for example, "A" will bring them to website X, "B will being them to website X, "N" will bring them to website Y, etc...

I'm very new to the programming world and know the basics of HTML and JavaScript, thus my survey is in HTML and JavaScript. I'm open to any suggestions. I wasn't sure if I could add the link into the HTML or if I needed to make an onclick function like I have in the JavaScript code. Any direction give would be greatly appreciated!

```js
var StoryMap = function(){
  var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("option");
  if (elements === "A"){
    alert("Thank you! Please go to this Story Map (link)");
  }else{
    alert("Please select the first letter of your last name");
  }
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title>Esri Story Map Study</title>
<script src="javascript.js"></script>
<link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>

<body>
<h2>The Windom Park Historic Residential District Pre-Survey</h2>

<h3>Please select the <span>first letter</span> of your <span>last name</span>: </h3>

<form>
  <p>
    <select name="firstLetter">
      <option value="Blank"></option>
      <option value="A">A</option>
      <option value="B">B</option>
      <option value="C">C</option>
      <option value="D">D</option>
      <option value="E">E</option>
      <option value="F">F</option>
      <option value="G">G</option>
      <option value="H">H</option>
      <option value="I">I</option>
      <option value="J">J</option>
      <option value="K">K</option>
      <option value="L">L</option>
      <option value="M">M</option>
      <option value="N">N</option>
      <option value="O">O</option>
      <option value="P">P</option>
      <option value="Q">Q</option>
      <option value="R">R</option>
      <option value="S">S</option>
      <option value="T">T</option>
      <option value="U">U</option>
      <option value="V">V</option>
      <option value="W">W</option>
      <option value="X">X</option>
      <option value="Y">Y</option>
      <option value="Z">Z</option>
  </p>
<input type="submit" name="next" value="Next"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Is this a form for submitting, too? If not, `<form>` is the wrong element and context to use.

Comment: I used the <form> elements because I want the program to bring the user to an outside link...

Answer (score 0):

document.getElementsByValue("option");

Comment: <input type="submit" name="next" value="Next" onclick="StoryMap();"/>

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken you can just make your option values equal to the website you want to take them to. For example:

```
<select name="firstletter">
    <option value="www.google.com">A</option>
    <option value="www.amazon.com">B</option>
    <option value="www.yahoo.com"> C</option>
</select>
```

Comment: that's what I was thinking too, but there needs to be a way for the user to hit "submit" and then they will be taken to that designated webpage..

Answer (score 0):

this help you :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            function StoryMap(){
              var ele = document.forms["frm"]["firstLetter"].value;
              if (ele == "A"){
                var link = "https://www.google.com";
                alert("Thank you! Please go to this Story Map " + link);
               }
               else{
                alert("Please select the first letter of your last name");
              }
            }
        </script>
        
        <h3>Please select the <span>first letter</span> of your <span>last name</span>: </h3>

<form name="frm" method="post" onsubmit="StoryMap()">
  <p>
    <select name="firstLetter">
      <option value="Blank"></option>
      <option value="A">A</option>
      <option value="B">B</option>
      <option value="C">C</option>
      <option value="D">D</option>
      <option value="E">E</option>
      <option value="F">F</option>
      <option value="G">G</option>
      <option value="H">H</option>
      <option value="I">I</option>
      <option value="J">J</option>
      <option value="K">K</option>
      <option value="L">L</option>
      <option value="M">M</option>
      <option value="N">N</option>
      <option value="O">O</option>
      <option value="P">P</option>
      <option value="Q">Q</option>
      <option value="R">R</option>
      <option value="S">S</option>
      <option value="T">T</option>
      <option value="U">U</option>
      <option value="V">V</option>
      <option value="W">W</option>
      <option value="X">X</option>
      <option value="Y">Y</option>
      <option value="Z">Z</option>
      </select>
<input type="submit" name="next" value="Next"/>
</form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't send data to your "new page" then you don't need `form` and, probably, button. The code is extremely simple.

```
<select onchange="redirToDestination(this)">
  <option value="Blank"></option>
  <option value="A">A</option>
  <option value="B">B</option>
  <option value="C">C</option>
  <option value="D">D</option>
  <option value="E">E</option>
  <option value="F">F</option>
</select>

...
function redirToDestination(elem){
   switch(elem.value){
     case 'A':
       window.location = 'newpage1.html';
       break;
     case 'B':
     case 'C':
       window.location = 'newpage2.html';
       break;
     ...
     default:
       alert('Select letter');
       break;
   }//switch
}//function
```

Comment: Okay so this makes sense...but then I need some way the user can get to that newpage1.html - can that be accomplished through a submit button? Does there need to be a separate onclick function to execute the switch statements?

I somehow need the user to be able to click on the "submit" button and it will bring them to their designated html page...based on whichever letter they choose

Comment: Add `alert('blah blah');` before `window.location=...`. The message will be shown and then when user click OK the page will be loaded to new location.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you